# Cookies not saving when using if isset $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, cookies

Sorry for asking this since I am fairly new to PHP, but I am trying to create a login system wherein a user logs in to enter a homepage. The login page sets cookies for the username and password if the user checks the Remember me checkbox regardless if login is successful or not. If login is successful, it starts a session. While there is an active session, the user cannot access the login page unless they log out. If login is not successful, it will redirect back to the login page. My problem here is that the cookies are not set regardless if the login is successful or not. But if I remove the if isset($_SESSION) statement, it successfully sets the cookies. Below is my code:

login.php:

```
<?php
  session_start();
if(isset($_POST["login"]))
{
  $remember = $_POST["remember"];
  if($remember == 1)
  {
    setcookie("username", $_POST["uname"], time()+86400);
    setcookie("password", $_POST["pwd"], time()+86400);
  }
  
  if(isset($_SESSION['uname']))
  {
    echo"<script>alert('Already logged in.')</script>";
    echo"<script>location.href = 'home.php'</script>";
  }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<style>

body
{
  background-color: DimGray;
}  

table
{
    font-family: Calibri; 
    color:white; 
    font-size: 14pt; 
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left; 
    background-color: DimGray; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    border: 2px solid white
}

table.inner
{
  border: 0px
}

.my_text
{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color:white; 
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
 
<body>
<div class = my_text> Login Page</div>   
<table align="center" cellpadding = "10">
 
<!----- Userame ---------------------------------------------------------->
<form method="post" action="home.php">
<tr>
<td>Username: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="uname" value = "<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["username"])) echo $_COOKIE["username"]?>"/>
</td>
</tr>
 
<!----- Password ---------------------------------------------------------->
<tr>
<td>Password: </td>
<td><input type="text" name="pwd" value = "<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["password"])) echo $_COOKIE["password"]?>"/>
</td>
</tr>

<!----- Remember me ------------------------------------------------->
<tr>
<td>Remember Me </td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="remember" value = "1"/>
</td>
</tr>

<!----- Submit ------------------------------------------------->
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="login">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<br>
<br>


</body>
</html>
```

home.php:

```
<?php
  $uname = "admin";
  $pwd   = "12345";

  session_start();

  if(isset($_SESSION['uname']))
  {
    echo"<table align='center' cellpadding = '10'>";
    echo"<tr><td>Welcome " . $_SESSION['uname'] . "</td></tr>";
    echo"<tr align = 'center'><td><a href = 'logout.php'><input type = button value = logout name logout></a></td></tr>";
  }

  else
  {
    if($_POST["uname"] == $uname && $_POST["pwd"] == $pwd)
    {
      $_SESSION["uname"] = $uname;
      echo"<script>location.href = 'home.php'</script>";
    }

    else
    {
      echo"<script>alert('Username or Password is incorrect.')</script>";
      echo"<script>location.href = 'login.php'</script>";
    }
    
  }
    

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<style>

body
{
  background-color: DimGray;
}  

table
{
    font-family: Calibri; 
    color:white; 
    font-size: 30pt; 
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left; 
    background-color: DimGray; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    border: 2px solid white
}

table.inner
{
  border: 0px
}

.my_text
{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color:white; 
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<div class = my_text> Home Page</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

logout.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['uname']))
    {
        session_destroy();
        echo"<script>location.href = 'login.php'</script>";
    }

    else
    {
        echo"<script>location.href = 'login.php'</script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: _"The login page sets cookies for the username and password"_ - that is a massive security fail right there already.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You started with `<table><form>...`, but the end is the other way around, `</table></form>`.